# Cucumber, how to write this line

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I did some selenium-webdriver ruby code. It works, but now I want to use cucumber to take advantage of the html report that looks good with green and red colors. When I started to use some code in the file called custom_steps.rb, it did not work.

1. Can you please tell me how to write this line in this file:

   ```
   require 'selenium-cucumber'

   # Do Not Remove This File
   # Add your custom steps here
   # $driver is instance of webdriver use this instance to write your custom code

   divs = $driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 check-box-container']/a/div");
   ```
2. How is the code from custom_steps.rb called in `.feature` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not called by that file, your step definition interprets meaning from the `.feature` file.

In your step definition file you need to write regular expressions to match the lines in the `.feature` file.

Here is an example of the syntax in action from dispora, a large rails app with many cucumber tests https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/21980681b156bc163c616cf0344bcdf3f3a195db/features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb.

Also see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby

Comment: Thanks, the dispora site is very helpful.

Comment: is there any site running diaspora., so I can use those tests to practice ? thanks,

Comment: Somewhere on their site https://diasporafoundation.org/ that code is running, but I'm not sure how much luck you will have with that approach, because their test setup looks quite complicated.